# is it possible to get parent element by its index number in jQuery? Or is there any other way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="topparent">
   <div class="secondparent">
       <div class="firstparent">
               <a href="#" class="link" >Menu Link</a>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

here I want to get `<div class="secondparent">` by jQuery or JavaScript. My code would be on Anchor Tag and i want to get its second most parent element by Index number. Or is there any other way? **I don't want get element by hard coded ID or CLASS.**

Comment: `.parent().parent()`

Comment: if there are 10 parents then i have to write a chain of .parent(). is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the class?

Comment: `$('a.link').parents().eq(1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** and **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

1. Using **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** you can get all ancestors
2. **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** will help to select by index

**CODE:**

```js
var p1=$('a.link').parents().eq(0);
var p2=$('a.link').parents().eq(1);
var p3=$('a.link').parents().eq(2);

console.log(p1.attr('class'),p2.attr('class'),p3.attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topparent">
   <div class="secondparent">
       <div class="firstparent">
               <a href="#" class="link" >Menu Link</a>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnaks!! @Pranav C Balan for quick response..!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi now you can used to **[parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)**

```js
var p1=$('a.link').parent();
var p2=$(p1).parent();
var p3=$(p2).parent();

console.log(p1.attr('class'),p2.attr('class'),p3.attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topparent">
   <div class="secondparent">
       <div class="firstparent">
               <a href="#" class="link" >Menu Link</a>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```